# Military Weapon System

Tags: language, password

[image: A keypad. At the top is a choice of four flags: German, French, Italian, and British. Then is an area with six blank spots marked "password". Beneath is an area with two blank spots marked "no.". Then the keys themselves: four rows of three keys apiece. The first row has "1 ABC", "2 DEF", and "3 GHI", and so on to "9 YZ" at the end of the third trow. The fourth row has "#", "0 .", and "=". The current state of the keypad is: the German flag is selected, the last three of the six spots for the password are green (the other three are grey), and there's an "F" in the last of the six.]

To access the Military Weapon System we need to enter a multi-language password with a keypad. There is a clue for the above selection and we can front attack it but maybe there is a trial limit. Trying the next buttons we got:

[image: The six spots for the password, of which the first two are grey and the others green. The second-to-last spot has a "Z".]

[image: The six spots for the password, all of which are green. The third spot has a "D".]

[image: The six spots for the password, all of which are green. The fourth spot has a "V".]

The other clues for French, Italian and English respectively are just single letter as well. But it make sense to think that all the passwords for different selection has the same meaning.So,what it might be?

Comment: I've downvoted because I don't think this is a high-quality puzzle, because there's no path to the solution. It seems to me that the only way to solve this is to try words of the right length until one of them fits. There's no insight or "aha moment".

Comment: there is a clue on the drawing that narrows it down

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The password(s) is/are:

> ELF, ONZE, UNDICI, ELEVEN (German, French, Italian, English words for the number $11$).

The clue:

> The EQUALS sign is an $11$ on it's side (hence NUMBER (#) $11$).